PostgreSQL EXPLAIN from EXECUTE statement
PostgreSQL 13.11
Is there a way of getting EXPLAIN ANALYZE from EXECUTE q_sql USING p1,p2 inside DO block/function?
I have to build query dynamically inside of function, and execution of query inside of function takes up to 60s (creating tmp table), but when query is run "by hand" with the same parameters exec_tm is in ms.

Use the auto_explain extension to capture the plan used by the function.

Yes you can create the query with explain analyze metrics, and execute that using Active Record connection executor to analyze the query performance inside a block or a method.
as
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query("EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * query)
